# How to manually invoke DSProxyGEN.EXE to generate Delphi DataSnap proxy client?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, datasnap

I am using DataSnap of Delphi 2010.  There is a DSProxyGen.EXE utility to allow us generate proxy client unit.  Does anyone how to consume this utility in command line to generate the proxy client without using TSQLConnection's context menu?

Answer (score 3):

DSProxyGen doesn't give you its parameters when run at the command line and doesn't respond to

```
DSProxyGen /?
```

You could try replacing it with your own exe (make a backup!) that detects what command line parameters are sent (global CmdLine variable) and write them to a file.  Launch this from TSQLConnection's context menu and you should have what you need to call DSProxyGen from the command line.

**Update:**

From Delphi XE to XE7, source code for DSProxyGen is included as one of the samples

```
Samples\Delphi\DataSnap\ProxyGenerator
```

In Delphi XE8, it is shipped as part of the source code.

```
source\data\datasnap\proxygen
```

Comment: Your solutions sounds work but I unable to make it works.  Here is what I did:

1. I rename DSProxyGen.exe to DSProxyGen.exe.old in folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\bin"
2. I then try to generate the proxy client class from TSQLConnection context menu and it still able to generate the unit.

It seems like the IDE didn't invoke DSProxyGen.exe

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: I tried running the exe to see if the command line parameters were documented, but didn't try replacing it.  I'll give it a shot when I get a little time.

Comment: See my answer, you can run DSProxyGen.exe (from XE and later) without parameters for usage help.

I've noticed the source is also included in Delphi XE7 and later:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\source\data\datasnap\proxygen\DSProxyGen.dproj

Comment: I made my update without reading your answer. You beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

DSProxyGen.exe without arguments connects using TCP/IP port 211 and uses the first command-line argument as filename.

DSProxyGen test.pas

Will generate test.pas

I've found no way to specify ConnectionString options on the command-line, yet...

Comment: Seems it has been added in Delphi XE :-)  ,see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with the DSProxyGen.exe from Delphi XE and later, for example:

```
DSProxyGen.exe Proxy.pas
-C:host=localhost;port=8080;communicationprotocol=http
```

Run DSProxyGen.exe *without parameters* for usage help. (/? or /h etc. does not work)

I've noticed the source is also included in Delphi XE7:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\source\data\datasnap\proxygen\DSProxyGen.dproj
```

Note that it would not work if you have specified any Transport Filters (ie. ZLibCompression,PC1,RSA etc.), returning errors for example "TDBXError: ZLibCompression Filter not found."

A temp workaround I've used during development time is to add another TDSTCPServerTransport comp that does not have any Transport Filters and then DSProxyGen works fine.

Answer (score 0):

See the unit DSProxyDesigner.dcu (for which the source file is not included, but should be at database\external\src\pas\datasnap\proxy\DSProxyDesigner.pas). This is the unit used at design-time to generate the proxy client classes. I'm not sure DSProxyGen.exe is actually used, and it's a shame there is no documentation on its command-line parameters, yet...

Comment: In Delphi XE, is it still the same (no documentation, no source code)?

Comment: Run Delphi XE's DSProxyGen.exe without parameters for usage help on the command-line parameters